# Is lying to prevent a great sin allowed?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, lying

Is it permissible to lie in order to avoid a great sin? For example, a person was invited to an inappropriate party, so he acted sick to slip away and not attend it. So in such cases, **would lying be allowed/encouraged?**

Comment: Compared to just saying "I do not want to go to the party" which would achieve the same result *without* lying?

Comment: For that case maybe yea, but I mean generally, is it permissible to do so in order to avoid a bigger sin?? @goldPseudo

Comment: Only when there is no other option...

Answer (score 2):

you cannot do it with the example you listed above because saying you don't want to go will have the same effect , in islam you can only lie to prevent to prevent hatred between people who have had a fight eg. he didn't mean to hit you etc.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider adding a reference to support your claims and read [answer]. I strongly recommend you to take our 2 min. [tour] and check our [help] to learn more about our model.

Answer (score 0):

lying is OK if it rightfully saves your life ( I mean it saves it from a tyrant. You can't lie to save your life from justice) or if reconciles the relationship between two Muslim brothers or sisters.

For such a situation you mentioned you have 2 options I'd say:

- Tell another reason, like I need to be at my house to clean my house. I need to study. I have some work to do. And even if you have work to do for 1 minute then still that's not lying
- EXPLAIN and elaborate why—to the extent they can understand. However if you think they will not understand at all, just say I'm not interested in such events. Period.

The general rule of lying is OK if prevents something greater, is only acceptable if there is No other alternative and that which you intend to protect is actually great. I don't think it applies to your situation because you have alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

Its not advisable to commit a sin to avoid another sin. This makes no sense, as you disobey Allah's commands regardless in which way.

Lying is never encouraged in Islam and is one of the bigger sins.

> The Prophet(s) said: "Lying leads to immorality, and immorality leads to
>   hellfire.[Kanz al-Ummal,8217]
>
> ---
>
> Imam Ali (as) said: "Cast aside lying, for it opposes faith. A
>   truthful person is on the verge of salvation and dignity, whereas a
>   liar is on the point o falling down and humiliation [Nahj-ul-
>   Balaghah, Sermon 86]

Comment: I read here https://islamqa.info/ar/154955 that lying is permitted if it is to prevent a greater sin. Which contradicts what you're saying.

Comment: when you know the answer than why not post your own answer and accept it?

Answer (score -1):

Take this question away from the thought of shading the true to prevent someone from being hurt or feeling bad. It is more a case of communication and being able to express yourself with those you would consider friends. Add to this what you cause within your own self that carries on after the event takes place. If you care about your friend and you want to build a deeper relationship with this person, look to there to answer this question.

Comment: Huh, i don't get you??

Comment: People need to look at the basic ability to communicate and treat each other honestly. If a person is someone you care about and they understand you, should you have a need to lie? We need to look at a basic ability to be open and real with each other. This would prevent any type of issue of having to lie or even concern themselves with how they come across. This would allow this world to begin to see people who care will be real, honest and thankful for words that help.